# Slow php/mysql results - display loading image?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a website that is running `php/MySQL` to query and return results. The result set is over 40,000 and the query is getting slower.  I want to find a simple way to display a loading image while the page builds.  I can do it with any page running JavaScript but I assume since php is server side I need to handle the loading differently.

I see that AJAX has a `load()` function where I can call the php page and presumable show a loading image while the request is loading.  Is that the best way?  I can't believe that there aren't lots of example scripts floating around since this has to be a very common problem.

Comment: why do you need to send 40,000 results at one time? Sounds like you need to expand on AJAX useage and send data on demand

Comment: "this has to be a very common problem"  It's not very common to returns 40,000 results.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have said, there are 40,000 people in my database now and I am running stats on those people.  So, not 40,000 returns - the stats are run against 40,000 entries in the database.  So, the query takes about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using an AJAX request to do this? If so, it's as simple as using JavaScript to display an image when you send the request, then hide it again upon success/error. You can just keep an `<img>` tag around with "display: none" and turn it on/off as needed.

If you aren't using AJAX, then this will be impossible, as the page does not exist until the query is completed.

On a side note: it's incorrect to say that "AJAX has a `load()` function". AJAX is not a code base or a library, it is a technique. Perhaps you mean jQuery.ajax, or some other library?

Comment: No, the request is done with php mysqli.  I have never used AJAX or jquery - hence the incorrect terminology.  I really just want to display a loading image while my php code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use Ajax, i reckon [Loading data from form into MySQL with PHP and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030072/loading-data-from-form-into-mysql-with-php-and-ajax) will be useful and follow the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for Ajax reference